# Microsoft Windows 64-bit application development best practises installation folder

Tags: windows, 64-bit

My problem is that a vendor is providing me with a 64bit application (packed in a 64bit installer) but it goes and installs to the x86 (Program Files) Folder and he keeps telling me its OK but I want it to install in the Program Files directory; as the 32 bit version does that and scripts for the app are developed based on this assumption.

Can someone direct me to the Microsoft recommended best practices for 64bit applications(links).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to `Program Files` is virtualised on 64-bit versions of Windows. As 64-bit application will see `C:\Program Files`, and a 32-bit application will **also** see `C:\Program Files` but Windows will virtualise the reads and writes for the 32-bit application to `C:\Program Files (x86)`. There is some documentation (not directly related) available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187(v=VS.85).aspx).

I do not think that the installer is actually 64-bit, or it is aware that it is installing a 64-bit application.

But to answer your question, you want the [Programming Guide for 64-bit Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb427430(v=VS.85).aspx).